# Will Updating to windows 11 Remove ubuntu from boot loader?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ssd

I have installed ubuntu on an external SSD to my windows 10. So whenever want to use ubuntu I simply connect External SSD with USB and enter through boot manager.

Recently I got a windows 11 update and I want to know if updating windows 11 will remove ubuntu from the boot loader even if I have installed ubuntu in external SSD?

Comment: IF Grub is installed in the ESP of the external drive and that drive is disconnected during the upgrade how exactly are you expecting it to be removed?

Comment: I have a dual-boot on my single SSD, and unlike previous Windows 10 updates that DID mess with GRUB/boot loader, my Windows 11 update did not. Have good backups anyway, your experience might be different.

Answer (score 2):

Nope! It will simply update your Windows partition. GRUB will remain the default boot loader. Windows 11 is kind of like a big Windows 10 update. Windows 11 still uses the Windows Boot Manager so GRUB will still recognize Windows. Nothing really changes. If for some reason GRUB is no longer the default boot loader, then go into your BIOS/UEFI and change boot order. There should be one called "ubuntu", set that above everything else and that should set GRUB as the default boot loader. I will warn you, Windows 11 took a long time to install, so maybe start it overnight. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If this answers your question, it'd be great if you would mark it as the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the upvote/downvote button.